# Scala - Define types for a number in a range

Tags: scala, validation, types, compile-time

I am wondering if I could define in Scala a type that wraps a number within a range and assert it's validity at compile time. For example: All numbers in range [0,1], so I could define a function taking the type BetweenZeroAndOne. I know I can define a case class that holds/wraps a number and then check if the number is between range at runtime, and that I can also use implicit conversions Int => BetweenZeroAndOne, Double => BetweenZeroAndOne, BetweenZeroAndOne => Int... But it is possible to define the type of numbers between zero and one?

Thanks,

Comment: If you talking about something like: data Bool = False | True   (in Haskel). Then I think you can not do this.

Comment: @Pavel I don't know a lot about haskell but your definition resembles hierarchy in OO, like True extends Bool, False extends Bool. I'm asking for continous values.

Comment: how big is you range by the way??

Comment: @Pavel From 0 to 1. Infinite numbers.

Comment: just posted possible approach using scala Enumeration's, could be good workaround etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [refined](https://github.com/fthomas/refined):

```
scala> type ZeroToOne = Not[Less[W.`0.0`.T]] And Not[Greater[W.`1.0`.T]]
defined type alias ZeroToOne

scala> refineMV[ZeroToOne](1.8)
<console>:40: error: Right predicate of (!(1.8 < 0.0) && !(1.8 > 1.0)) failed:
Predicate (1.8 > 1.0) did not fail.
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is possible solution, hope I understand your question correctly:
Purely using build in scala functionality:

```
object MyInt extends Enumeration {
  type MyInt = Value
  // this is most "fragile" part of this solution
  val Zero, One, Two, Three = Value
}

object MyIntToIntConverter{
  import MyInt._
  implicit def MyIntToInt(x: MyInt) : Int = x.id
  implicit def IntToMyInt(x: Int) : MyInt = MyInt.apply(x)
}

import MyInt._
import MyIntToIntConverter._

val x : Int  = MyInt.Three

val t : MyInt = 3
```

Comment: This solution is only for discrete ranges, isn't it?